# How to match this syntax group?

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting, regular-expression, syntax

I'm trying to improve on the MySQL syntax highlighting, for my particular code base.

I have a lot of this sort of thing

```
FROM   TBL_ENTITIES E
JOIN   TBL_RELATED_ENTITIES RE  ON  RE.entityFK  =  E.entityPK
```

My table nams are always uppercase and always start with TBL_, and my aliases are always uppercase and 1-3 characters long.

In this example, I'd like to create a syntax group `mysqlQualifier` for `RE` and `E`.

In the ON clause (and further use when they're a qualifier before a column name) it seems quite trivial

`syn match mysqlQualifier "\<[A-Z]\+\."`

That correctly picks up on "RE." and "R."  **(Though I'd prefer it not to highlight the period if possible!)**

But the alias clause is proving harder.  I'm sure it'll be very simple to someone who's edited a syntax file before, but this is all new to me.

This is what I've tried, based on my understanding of [Custom syntax highlighting: highlight word following keyword](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7709/custom-syntax-highlighting-highlight-word-following-keyword) :

```
syn match mysqlTable             "TBL_[A-Z_]\+" nextgroup=mysqlQualifier skipwhite
syn match mysqlQualifier         "\<[A-Z]\+\>" contained
```

But it doesn't seem to work, and matches far too much (e.g. `COALESCE` when `COALESCE` *hasn't* immediately followed a table name.

I thought maybe I could simply match one, and then match the other, so as to "overwrite" part of it:

```
syn match mysqlQualifier         "TBL_[A-Z_]\+.\s\+[A-Z]\+"
syn match mysqlTable             "TBL_[A-Z_]\+"
```

But the second match seems to undo the first one; `TBL_ENTITIES` correctly recognised as a table, but `E` is not recognised as a qualifier, so I guess syntax can't be "overwritten" in the way that I hoped it might.

**EDIT:** I've now improved on the above...

```
syn match mysqlTable2            "TBL_[A-Z_]\+"

syn match mysqlQualifier         "TBL_[A-Z_]\+.\s\+[A-Z]\+" contains=mysqlTable
syn match mysqlTable             "TBL_[A-Z_]\+" contained
syn match mysqlQualifier         "[A-Z]\+\."
```

This is almost perfect, with one exception - I still have the problem with the period being hightlighted after the qualifier, e.g. in `RE.entityFK`.

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `\ze` to mark end of the match:

```
syn match mysqlTable2            "TBL_[A-Z_]\+"

syn match mysqlQualifier         "TBL_[A-Z_]\+.\s\+[A-Z]\+" contains=mysqlTable
syn match mysqlTable             "TBL_[A-Z_]\+" contained
syn match mysqlQualifier         "[A-Z]\+\ze\."
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Although the rest of what I've put together *works*... I think it's probably kludgy - is there a better way to achieve what I wanted?  Thank you :-)

Comment: Well, I would stop at "good enough" solution until rough edges would bother you enough to fix it.

Comment: Wise words Maxim!