# Custom syntax highlighting: highlight match following keyword

Tags: syntax-highlighting

This question might be related to [Custom syntax highlighting: highlight word following keyword](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7709/custom-syntax-highlighting-highlight-word-following-keyword) but after studying that for hours, I could not get it to work.

What I want is to highlight vulkan types that match `vk::(Instance|Device)` (in reality a much longer expression, but this will do as example).

It should not match `vk::InstanceCreateInfo` (because that is a different type).
It should work when this match is contained inside a unrelated region. For example, I have a very complex regions that match parenthesis for different type of things; so complex that I really don't want this to be added as exception too. Yet, the highlight should work in code like:

```
void setup(vk::Instance vh_instance, vk::SurfaceKHR surface, DeviceCreateInfo&& device_create_info);
```

Aka, work while contained inside region `cParen`.

I already have:

```
syn keyword cwNamespaceTag vk
```

which is auto-generated; I'd prefer to be able to leave that alone. But if necessary it can be changed.

I tried the following (already changing the above keyword):

```
syn keyword cwNamespaceVkTag vk nextgroup=cwVulkanHandle
syn match cwVulkanHandle '\v::(Instance|Device)>' contained
```

but that fails in that `::Device` in

```
void setup(foo::Device foo);
```

is highlighted (because it is contained (in cParen). Obviously this is not what I want; `cwVulkanHandle` should *only* be enabled when immediately following `cwNamespaceVkTag`.

I also tried,

```
syn keyword cwNamespaceVkTag vk contained
syn match cwVulkanHandle '\v<vk::(Instance|Device)>' contains=cwNamespaceVkTag
```

but that highlights `vk` (as `cwNamespaceVkTag`) and then `cwVulkanHandle` isn't used anymore for some reason. When I remove the keyword line then the match works. It seems that the fact that `vk` already matches a keyword stops the `region` from matching against it, despite that I say that it contains it.

How can I get this to work?

EDIT:

This,

```
syn match cwNamespaceVkTag /vk::\(Instance\|Device\)\>/ contains=cwVulkanHandle
syn match cwVulkanHandle /::\w\+/ contained
```

leads to

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved on, after hacking something together that works for now:

```
" Add syntax group for vulkan types that are handles.

" The regular expression was generated with:
" RE=$(egrep '^(VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE|VK_DEFINE_HANDLE)' Vulkan-Hpp/Vulkan-Headers/include/vulkan/vulkan_core.h | sed -e 's/.*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/;s/^Vk//' | sort | awk '{ printf("%s|", $0); }' | sed -e 's/^/(/;s/|$/)/')
syn match cwNameSpaceTag "\v<vk>"
syn match cwVulkanHandle "\v<vk::(AccelerationStructureKHR|AccelerationStructureNV|Buffer|BufferView|CommandBuffer|CommandPool|CuFunctionNVX|CuModuleNVX|DebugReportCallbackEXT|DebugUtilsMessengerEXT|DeferredOperationKHR|DescriptorPool|DescriptorSet|DescriptorSetLayout|DescriptorUpdateTemplate|Device|DeviceMemory|DisplayKHR|DisplayModeKHR|Event|Fence|Framebuffer|Image|ImageView|IndirectCommandsLayoutNV|Instance|PerformanceConfigurationINTEL|PhysicalDevice|Pipeline|PipelineCache|PipelineLayout|PrivateDataSlotEXT|QueryPool|Queue|RenderPass|Sampler|SamplerYcbcrConversion|Semaphore|ShaderModule|SurfaceKHR|SwapchainKHR|ValidationCacheEXT)>"hs=s+4 contains=cwNamespaceTag
syn match cwVulkanHandle "\v<Vk(AccelerationStructureKHR|AccelerationStructureNV|Buffer|BufferView|CommandBuffer|CommandPool|CuFunctionNVX|CuModuleNVX|DebugReportCallbackEXT|DebugUtilsMessengerEXT|DeferredOperationKHR|DescriptorPool|DescriptorSet|DescriptorSetLayout|DescriptorUpdateTemplate|Device|DeviceMemory|DisplayKHR|DisplayModeKHR|Event|Fence|Framebuffer|Image|ImageView|IndirectCommandsLayoutNV|Instance|PerformanceConfigurationINTEL|PhysicalDevice|Pipeline|PipelineCache|PipelineLayout|PrivateDataSlotEXT|QueryPool|Queue|RenderPass|Sampler|SamplerYcbcrConversion|Semaphore|ShaderModule|SurfaceKHR|SwapchainKHR|ValidationCacheEXT)>"

hi def link cwVulkanHandle cVulkanHandle                    " Highlight vulkan handle types.
```

For this to work I also had to make sure that the previous `keyword` rule for `vk` was no longer generated.

Or as short version that we used here as example / test case:

```
syn match cwNameSpaceTag "\v<vk>"
syn match cwVulkanHandle "\v<vk::(Instance|Device)>"hs=s+4 contains=cwNamespaceTag
```

The main trick here is using a match for the namespace `vk` instead of a keyword. Apparently a keyword always has a higher precedence, so when that exists you can not add a match that contains it. By using another `match` it works: when the match that follow the first one matches, it become the one that is picked, overruling the first more general match.

My conclusion is that vim's highlighting interface needs a rewrite: for most things that are just a little bit more advanced one quickly has to resort to hacks and far from intuitive. I suppose that the preferred method (for C++) would be one that is based of llvm (clang).

Things that I ran into:

1. It is not possible to delete/remove a rule later on (ie, a keyword rule).
2. It is not possible to explicitly state that rule should ONLY match when contained in LIST, automatically avoiding any existing rules with a `contains=ALL_BUT,...` without having to add to each and every such list.
3. I could not figure out how (seems not possible) to match a `start` pattern against text that was already matched (`vk::`), which made it impossible to even begin to use regions here.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
syn region cParen start=/setup(/ end=/)/ contains=cwNamespaceVkTag
syn match cwNamespaceVkTag /\<vk::\(Instance\|Device\)\>/ contains=cwVulkanHandle contained
syn match cwVulkanHandle /::\w\+/ contained
```

I didn't use the `\v` (very magic) atom because I'm more used to Vim's "standard" regular expression format.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was sleeping. Thank you for your help. I tried it and added a picture of the result to my answer (see below 'EDIT'). The main problem is still that when contained inside cParen the match rule for cwVulkanHandle still matches.

Comment: Try the containedin to specify where, and a word boundary at the front to prevent spurious matches like vvk

Comment: @CarloWood: I've edited my answer, see if it helps?

Comment: Now it highlights *every* `::\w\+`.

Comment: I forgot that containedin still means contained is needed. I edited again.

Comment: That is the same as having just `contained`. Of course this fixes the `vvk::` thingy, but not the fact that it is matched whenever it is contained by anything. `containedin` is just a way to add something to an existing rule that doesn't have a `contains` for it, but since `cwNamespaceVkTag` already does, the `containedin` does nothing.

Comment: Yes, I should've made it explicit that you would also have had to make cwNamespaceVkTag contained in cParen in the same manner.  I have edited my answer.

Comment: That doesn't add anything; on the contrary, it doesn't address the problem that I desribed it activates the problem. My cParen already contains ALL. I have no idea why this was upvoted, because it simply doesn't work. I appreciate your effort, but it seems you're just guessing without testing things out. I can do that too, it is not an "Answer", they are suggestions, and none of them solve the problem.

Comment: No, I'm actually testing, but YOU are NOT PROVIDING ENOUGH INFORMATION for us to do what you ask.